# AttachInterrupt in a library

Tags: arduino

I'm having trouble adding attachInterrupt in a library that I am creating. I researched a lot, and I noticed that this is a common mistake, but do not quite understand the answers I found.

The error in question is this:

```
sketch_nov04a.ino: In function 'void setup()':
sketch_nov04a:10: error: argument of type 'void (Teste::)()' does not match 'void (*)()'
```

My library is as follows:

**Teste.h**

```
#ifndef TESTE_H
#define TESTE_H
#include <Arduino.h>

class Teste
{
public:
    volatile long lastWindIRQ;
    volatile byte windClicks;

  void wspeedIRQ();
};
#endif
```

**Teste.cpp**

```
#include "Teste.h"

void Teste::wspeedIRQ()
{
  if (millis() - this.lastWindIRQ > 10)
  {
    this.lastWindIRQ = millis();
    this.windClicks++;
  }
}
```

**my implementation**

```
#include <Teste.h>

Teste teste;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  attachInterrupt(0, teste.wspeedIRQ, FALLING);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println(teste.windClicks);
  delay(3000);
}
```

**The solution to this problem can be found here** -> https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/4865/3837

Comment: Need to state the answers you found and what you don't understand.

Comment: How much experience do you have writing libraries? looks like you have no constructor and are not calling the object. The error is because "windClicks" does not exist in your code anywhere. Normally you would have a global variable that you could manipulate by passing the pointer into your library. Then call a method inside the library from the interrupt.

Comment: @djUniversal It doesn't look like OP intends to use an object. The method is declared `static`. (Maybe the compiler will complain if OP doesn't also use `static` in the definition.) Otherwise, the library looks fine.

Comment: Just trying to check his intent some i don't see where/how he is trying to pull that variable and that is what the compiler is upset about. He will also need to declare the method outside the attachinterrupt. Wanted to know how much help he needs to fiddle with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here: an ISR can't take any arguments; and you are using a variable that hasn't been declared.

No guarantee that this will work, but you might try

```
#include <Teste.h>

volatile long lastWindIRQ;
volatile byte windClicks = 0;

void myISR ()
{
    Teste::wspeedIRQ(&lastWindIRQ, &windClicks);
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  attachInterrupt(0, myISR, FALLING);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println(windClicks);
  delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: That still probably wont work. His libraries need to be re-written.